# Google sheets - multiply two columns, copy third column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, syntax, range, multiplication

probably very simple question but yeah, dont know how of course.

I have 3 columns:

```
A  B  C
-------
5  1  A
5  2  B
5  3  C
```

and want to multiply column A and B, and just copy C column. All with one expresion.
So Result of multiplication A and B should be in D and result of copying should be in F:

Final result should be:

```
D F
---
5 A
10 B
15 C
```

Is there any simple method to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do:

```
=INDEX({A1:A3*B1:B3, C1:C3})
```

or if you are on non-english sheet:

```
=INDEX({A1:A3*B1:B3\ C1:C3})
```

Comment: Yeah, simple and working solution, love it!

Comment: Anyway I was trying the =INDEX({A1:A3*B1:B3; C1:C3}) - but it was creating the vector.
And it was the reason why I have put the question here 
So what differences are in "english" and "non-english" sheets?

Comment: @tomm using a semicolon `;` in array `{ }` means (in both versions) to put something under something else. to put something next to something else you need to use a comma `,` within english sheets and backslash \ within non-english sheets